# How do I do a scan over a table in KDB?

Tags: kdb

```
t: ([] a: til 10; b: til 10)
a b
---
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
```

I'm trying to get it to sum `a`, and upsert it, leaving `b` in place. I don't want to use q-sql for it.

I think it should be something like:

```
({x[`a]: x`a + y`a}\) t
```

I keep getting `'type` errors though, on the indexing operation.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

An even simpler example,

```
({x[`a]: 3}\) t
```

Same error. Expected result:
q)

```
a b
---
3 0
3 1
3 2
3 3
3 4
3 5
3 6
3 7
3 8
3 9
```

What am I'm trying to achieve in pseudocode:
assign case:

```
for each row in t
  row[`a]: 3
```

For the summation case:

```
for each row in t
  row[`a]: row_prior[`a] + row[`a]
```

Comment: `t[\`a]:sums t\`a` is this the result you want?

Comment: I'm specifically not using q-sql, as this is a toy example for a real problem. It needs to be done using iterators.

Comment: the above statement is not q-sql. Can you confirm this is the result you want?

Comment: `sums` is just `(+\)`

Comment: It isn't. I want to assign t\`a inside the loop, so I end up with a dictionary upsert.

I'm ultimately trying to build a state machine in a table, and an algorithm sucks in the last row (state) and returns a new row.

Comment: @S.Stewart I've added an even simpler example; it seems like the issue is with the assignment.

Comment: Can you amend your question to include expected result please.

Comment: @S.Stewart I've added the expected result for the second example

Comment: It looks like you are set on using scan (backslash) as opposed to over (/) . This means you are expecting intermediate results. Would you be able to post say the first 2 or 3 outputs you are expecting instead of just the final result? That would help cresting an answer

Comment: I am, I was hoping to update the table line by line. My logic was, if `t` is a list of dicts, I should be able to upsert each dict one at a time, and then the final result would be an updated table.

Comment: I've added two examples in pseudocode of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I've managed to figure it out; thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the answer; you have to return after the assignment:

```
({y[`a]: y[`a]+x[`a]; y}\) t

a  b
----
0  0
1  1
3  2
6  3
10 4
15 5
21 6
28 7
36 8
45 9
```

Comment: You could also avoid the assignment with something like ```({y+`b _x}\)t```